# replicating css for mobile version of Newsdaily

Tags: css

I really need help in developing a mobile website and tried many fonts but somehow not matching
Finally i found this leading news daily - where mobile version matches in exactly the need

`https://auto.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/passenger-vehicle/cars/covid-19-will-it-boost-cars-sales-whats-in-store-for-ride-hailing/74925368`

Though tried using firefox and google chrome but not able to get in font used and background that light grey color theme

I know this may not be what stackoverflow all about but any help in getting me font used, size, gap, line-height and background color theme for mobile version of page would be great.

Somehow i tried using

```
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: 
    #333;
    line-height: 1em;
```

but not getting in desired result. Thanks

Comment: use this chrome extension to get info about which fonts any website is using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en